# $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}[a_k-\int_{k}^{k+1}f(x)dx]$ question about proof of convergence.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

Given conditions of integral test for convergence and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=\infty(a_n \to0)$
Book says let's observe this $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}[a_k-\int_{k}^{k+1}f(x)dx]$ ($*$)

We have $a_{k+1}\leq\int_{k}^{k+1}f(x)dx\leq a_{k+1}$  $k=1,2...,n$

From this 0 $\leq$ $a_k-\int_{k}^{k+1}f(x)dx\leq a_k-a_{k+1}$

Because $a_n$ is decreasing to $0$ then ($*$) is convergent and writing it's sum as $C$ we get

$\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k-\int_{1}^{n+1}f(x)dx=\sum_{k=1}^{n}[a_k-\int_{k}^{k+1}f(x)dx]$ $\to$ $C$

Can you explain if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$  = $\infty$ how follows that $*$ series converges?

And $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k=\int_{1}^{n+1}f(x)dx+C+\gamma_n$  ,

$\gamma_n\to0$ and says that $C\leq a_1$ Can you help how he got that $C\leq a_1$

Comment: What's the limit of $(a_n)$? Summing $0\le a_k-\int_{k}^{k+1}f(x)\,\mathrm dx\leq a_k-a_{k+1}$ gives you that the series of non-negative terms
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\left(a_k-\int_k^{k+1}f(x)\,\mathrm dx\right)$$
is non-decreasing towards a limit $C\le a_1-\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}.$

Comment: Thanks @nejimban I added one more question regarding convergence of series.

Comment: Shouldn't the other question be answered now? You could consider the following example ($a_k:=\frac1k$, $f(x):=\frac1x$): $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k$$ diverges, but $$\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac1k-\int_k^{k+1}\frac{\mathrm dx}x\right)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k-\ln(n+1)$$ is converging.

Comment: Yes @nejimban but one example is not enough for proof.I am thinking about proof but can't do.

Comment: Thanks @nejimban now I understand your comment!